# Receiving loaders error when using NPM run start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I've encountered an issue today where whilst trying to install some packages through npm install I received multiple errors. I've gone to the lengths of uninstalling node, reinstalling, deleting node_modules and package-lock file as well. I've managed to install these new packages however when I try to run my app using npm run start I'm met with this error.

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@jclem/logfmt2/dist/string-scanner.js 11:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:6)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| class StringScanner {
>   data;
| 
|   constructor(data) {
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Trott as I forgot to add in those details! My version of Node is v14.0.0 and NPM is 6.14.4 as for the commands that started these issues was: `npm install @self.id/3box-legacy @self.id/core`

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "3box": "^1.19.1",
    "3box-profile-edit-react": "^0.0.9",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.0.0-alpha.46",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.0.0-alpha.46",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.46",
    "@metamask/detect-provider": "^1.2.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^3.2.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.4",
    "@self.id/3box-legacy": "^0.1.0",
    "@self.id/core": "^0.1.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.4",
    "@svgr/cli": "^5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@toruslabs/torus-embed": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.5",
    "@walletconnect/web3-provider": "^1.3.3",
    "authereum": "^0.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.26.0",
    "bitski": "^0.10.9",
    "blockies-ts": "^1.0.0",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "check-prop-types": "^1.1.2",
    "eth-price": "^0.1.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.2",
    "fortmatic": "^2.2.1",
    "get-eth-price": "^1.0.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "i18next": "^19.8.3",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^49.0.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "profile-hover": "^1.1.2",
    "query-string": "^4.3.4",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.2",
    "react-grid-layout": "^1.2.5",
    "react-grid-system": "^7.1.1",
    "react-i18next": "^10.13.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.1",
    "react-pdf": "^5.3.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "truffle-contract": "^4.0.31",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "use-wallet": "^0.10.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1",
    "web3": "^1.3.5",
    "web3modal": "^1.9.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "svgr": "svgr -d src/components/atoms/Icons/ src/assets/Icons"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ethereumjs-util": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.9"
  }
}
```

Also here are some of the errors/warnings I got whilst installing

```
npm WARN check-prop-types@1.1.2 requires a peer of prop-types@<=15.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-edge-launcher@0.4.2 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-junit-reporter@1.2.0 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-mocha-reporter@2.2.5 requires a peer of karma@>=0.13 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN pdfjs-dist@2.9.359 requires a peer of worker-loader@^3.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-addons-css-transition-group@15.6.2 requires a peer of react@^15.4.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\ipfs\node_modules\aegir\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\ipfs\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: Give people who want to help you a fighting chance of succeeding. Show your package.json and your code, the command you run, and the installation error you're receiving. Also report the version of Node.js and npm that you are using.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message, like "You must install peer dependencies yourself"?

Comment: Yeah I managed to install all the peer dependencies apart from the ```react-addons-css-transition-group``` as my current version of react is higher than the peer needed